# query less than infinity on creation date in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I need to filter all users that were created two months ago from today's date (today's date has to be dynamic and not fixed). But the active record doesn't understand exactly what I want. I make this query:

```
range_expired = ((2.months.ago).end_of_day)..((Date.today).end_of_day)
current_status = StudentStatusChange.where(created_at < range_expired)
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve this: `specific_date = Date.today - 2.month; current_status = StudentStatusChange.where("created_at < ?", specific_date)`

Comment: @Masroor your query is about records that older than 2 months ago :)

Comment: yes, I wasn't sure whether OP is trying to compare against the exact date since he's trying a `<` comparison in the query but also saying 2 months ago. For the exact date, it'd have to be `specific_date = Date.today - 2.month; StudentStatusChange.where(created_at: specific_date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all records from 2 months ago (exclude) to today's date (include) as you tried, you can use something like this

```rb
range_expired = 2.months.ago.end_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day

StudentStatusChange.where(created_at: range_expired)
```

Other variants:

```rb
# works in ruby >= 2.6
range_expired = 2.months.ago.end_of_day..
StudentStatusChange.where(created_at: range_expired)
```

```rb
StudentStatusChange.where("created_at > ?", 2.months.ago.end_of_day)
StudentStatusChange.where("created_at > :two_months_ago", two_months_ago: 2.months.ago.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one line solution to your problem:

```rb
StudentStatusChange.where(created_at: Date.today - 2.months..Date.today)
```

Above Query would return the results from StudentStatusChange object that were created in the duration of the last two months.